# Changing devices to which predefined stream objects are connected

Tags: c++, stream

By default when a c++ application where the  header is included, the following 4 stream objects are instantiated, **cin, cout, cerr** and **clog**(corresponding wide character types are also instantiated).

Now by default **cin** is connected to the standard input device which is usually the keyboard and **cout, cerr** and **clog** are connected to the standard output device which is usually the console.

My question is how we can change the devices these predefined stream objects are connected to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and no it doesn't depend on the operating system. Here's a quick demo, redirecting `cout` to write to a file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() { 
    // create a file buf, and open it on a file named "your_output.txt":
    std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > b;
    b.open("your_output.txt", std::ios_base::out);

    // connect `std::cout` to the chosen file via our file_buf:
    std::cout.rdbuf(&b);

    // write some output (which shouldn't show up on screen.
    std::cout << "This is some junk";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that as a rule, I'd recommend against this though. It's generally much cleaner (for one example) to move the code into a function that takes a reference to an ostream as its parameter, then pass the appropriate ostream or ofstream as needed. On the other hand, if you have (for example) a big chunk of existing code that already has reads/writes from/to standard streams coded in, this can let that work without rewriting it all.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a helper class similar to this one:

```
class RedirectOutput
{
    std::ostream &os_;
    std::filebuf f_;
    std::streambuf *obuf_;
    RedirectOutput (const RedirectOutput &);  // disallow
    void operator = (const RedirectOutput &); // disallow
public:
    RedirectOutput (std::ostream &os,
                    std::string where,
                    std::ios::openmode mode = std::ios::out)
        : os_(os.flush()) {
        f_.open(where.c_str(), mode);
        obuf_ = os.rdbuf(&f_);
    }
    ~RedirectOutput () {
        os_.flush();
        os_.rdbuf(obuf_);
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
{
   RedirectOutput ro(std::cout, "output.txt");
   std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "Goodbye" << std::endl;
```

`Hello` goes to the file `output.txt`, while `Goodbye` goes to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the operating system, but on Unix-like systems you can't do this while the program is running.  You have to set it when you launch the process.

For example, if you ran your program this way in the `zsh` shell:

```
./myprogram < file1  > file2  2> file3
```

...then `cin` reads from `file1`, `cout` writes to `file2` and `cerr` writes to `file3`.

Comment: +1 for providing the answer, but since I am working on windows, can't test it. But thanks for the effort.