# Trying to create an output file with freopen, using non-constant string

Tags: c++, string, freopen

I'm trying to create a file whose name is a string constant, but a string consisting of a constant string "List" an integer + + an extension. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (){
            int cont=0;

            std::string result;
            std::string name = "Lista";
            std::string ext = ".txt";

            char numstr[21]; // enough to hold all numbers up to 64-bits
            sprintf(numstr, "%d", cont);
            result = name + numstr+ext;

            freopen (result, "w", stdout);
            cout<<result<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

When I try to build tells me the following error:

> error: cannot convert `std::string' to`const char*' for argument `1'
>   to`FILE* freopen(const char*, const char*, FILE*)'|

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the compiler error states there is no implicit conversion from  `std::string` to `char const*` (ie. a *c-style-string* in this context).

Though `std::string` has a *member-function* named [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) which will generate a *null-terminated* string and return a pointer to it that is very usable when dealing with legacy C functions.

---

#### Examples and notes

```
freopen (result.c_str (), "w", stdout);
```

```
char const * p = result.c_str ();
```

<sup>Please note that the *c-style-string* pointed towards by `std::string::c_str` will be invalidated if you make any modifications to the hosting object (in this case `result`), therefore it is normally not wise to store the value returned in a non-temporary variable.</sup>

---

**You can read more about the function if you follow the link below**:

- **[cppreference.com - std::basic_string::c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)**

Answer (score 2):

i have a [small app](http://github.com/iKlsR/pclc) that does this exactly. there are several ways to do this.. the simplest of which is

```
const char * newvar = stringname.c_str();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use `sprintf`, it's probably easiest to skip using `std::string` at all:

```
char name[32];

sprintf(name, "lista%d.txt", cont);
freopen(name, "w", stdout);
```

If you're going to use `std::string` (probably preferable for most C++ anyway), you probably want to use `std::stringstream` to create the name:

```
std::ostringstream name;

name << "lista" << cont << ".txt";

freopen(name.str().c_str(), "w", stdout);
```

However, I'd tend to avoid `freopen` in general, *and* avoid using C-style streams (such as stout) in C++. It's generally better to write to an `ostream`. Answers to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11445182/179910) show how to connect `cout` to a different output file, if you truly need to.