# Writing a file with different extension but with same name as the file being read?

Tags: c++, file, opencv, file-handling

Using freopen I want to write to a file with same name as the file i am reading in the program but with differnt extension ?

suppose i am  reading file abc.jpg
I want to write in file abc.txt in the same program .

I am giving the initials of the files as argument but getting compilation error.
I am reading multiple files and writing to multiple files.

```
  freopen ( "abc" + ".txt" , "w" , stdout ) ;

  error : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std:string' to 'char *'
```

Comment: For future reference, anytime your question involves a compiler error, please post it.

Comment: Thanks; in this particular case the problem is easily spotted without seeing the compiler error, but I wanted to suggest it for future posts; the more detail the better!

Comment: Duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463674/trying-to-create-an-output-file-with-freopen-using-non-constant-string

Comment: This error message doesn't match your code; the expression `"abc" + ".txt"` should give a completely different error message, as dvnrrs tries to convey in his answer.  The actual error message you posted would be generated by code like:  `std::string s("abc"); freopen(s + ".txt", ...)`

Comment: Also, `freopen` expects `char const *` so it's a bit odd that the compiler message would drop the `const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator does not do string concatenation with two string literals. In C++ (going by your tags), you can use `std::string` to do the concatenation:

```
#include <string>

...

std::string baseFilename("abc");
std::string newFilename(baseFilename + ".txt");

freopen(newFilename.c_str(), "w", file);
```

The `std::string` class *does* support concatenation via `+`. Note that we're using `c_str()` because the `freopen()` function still takes a C-style string pointer (`const char *`).

Comment: new error : cannot convert parameter const char * to char * ;

Comment: on the same line as freopen ; says conversion loses qualifiers

Comment: @AmitKumar That's very strange. What compiler / platform are you using? It almost sounds like your C standard library has a very broken (non-standard-compliant) [signature for `freopen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/) which takes a `char *` instead of a `const char *`...

Comment: i am using visual studio 2010 and using opencv libraries to read a grayscale image and print the pixel values in the .txt file .

Comment: @AmitKumar Is your code *exactly* as mine above? VS2010 has a [correct signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk2h68td%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for `freopen()` so this doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score -1):

As written in question it is C not C++.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
FILE* fp;
```

...

```
freopen ( (std::string("abc")+std::string(".txt")).c_str() , "w" , fp ) ;
```

as function takes const char* and file pointer FILE*.